# Lookup to picture name of picture library in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, image, lookupfield

I have a picture library and I want to lookup to the name of picture in another generic list. I've tried:

```
lookupField.LookupField = "Name";
```

Then when I create a new item of this generic list, the picture lookup column show the list name of picture correctly, but after saving item this column is changed to blank.
Am I doing anything wrong here? Do I have to use other internal field name instead of "Name"?
Pleaze help...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found another solution. because I can not lookup to default name of picture library, so I create a hidden text field for picture library. This hidden field will get value of name in ItemUpdated event (no need ItemAdded because when I upload a new pic, it also called ItemUpdated <-- don't know why...)

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties) {
    properties.ListItem["HiddenImageName"] = properties.ListItem["Name"].ToString();
    properties.ListItem.Update();
}
```

Generic list will look up to this hidden field instead of default name field of Picture library